# angular/nodesjstools: How to say nodesjstools of vs2017 to use other nodes_module to install a package?

Tags: angular, npm, visual-studio-2017, package

when I ceate a **.Net core web application**, you know it insert different directories between them **wwwroot**.

I open a **cmd window**, and go to *wwwroot/CV* directory,  and I write inside **wwwroot** next command to create an **angular project**:

```
ng new CV
```

for example. **nodes_module** is created inside **CV**.

My idea is to use **nodejstools** of **vs2017** to generate **packages** but when I write next instruction in the **console of nodesjs**:

```
.npm install jquery
```

it creates a new **nodes_module** in the **project level** instead of **wwwroot/cv**.

How can I say to nodesjs of **vs2017** to use the **nodes_module** of **wwwroot/cv** which I created using **ng new CV**?

Comment: Don't ever create your app in the **wwwroot** because its the public folder of your app that the client can access, imagine you're putting the **node_modules** there and if you published the app that folder will be included, put only the generated main and vendor bundle assets in there, and better generate the app outside of the **wwwroot**,

Comment: then I have to move **CV directory content** in the **project level** right?

Comment: Yes you should move it